# How to implement AVL tree rotation?

Tags: python, recursion, avl-tree

I have coded an AVL Tree and my logic for the rotations is correct but I am still not able to get it working properly. For rotations on the root node my rotations work properly but if the rotation is further down the tree, the parent node does not point to the new node that has been rotated into place and continues to point to the node that was in place before the rotation. I am pretty sure the issues lies with my insert method but I am not sure how to get the parent node to point to the new node when a rotation occurs. I know you can add a parent variable to fix this but I am wondering if there is a way to do it without that.

```
For example
               10                                     10                                10
            /      \                                /   \           instead of         /    \
           8        12     Rotates to ->            8    12                          6      12
          /          \                                    \                         / \      \
         6            14                                    14                     4   8       14
         /                                        4 and 6 are lost
        4
```

```
class AVL():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.height = 0
        self.balf = 0
    
    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getHeight(self):
        return self.height
  
    def heightCalc(self,node):
        
        if node is None:
            return -1
        else:
            return max(self.heightCalc(node.left), self.heightCalc(node.right)) + 1 
    
    def getBalanceFactor(self):      
        return self.balf
   
    def balCheck(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return -1
        else:
            return self.heightCalc(node.left) - self.heightCalc(node.right)
      
    def insert(self, data):
         if data is not None:   
            if self.data is None:
                self.data = data
            else:
                if data < self.data:
                    if self.left is None:
                        self.left = AVL(data)                   
                    else:
                        self.left.insert(data)                      
                elif data >= self.data:
                    if self.right is None:
                        self.right = AVL(data)                        
                    else:
                        self.right.insert(data)                       
        
         self.height=self.heightCalc(self)
         self.balf = self.balCheck(self)
         
         if self.balf > 1:
             if self.left.getBalanceFactor() < 0:
                 self.left = self.left.leftRotate()
                 return self.rightRotate()
             else:
                  
                  return self.rightRotate()
         elif self.balf < -1:
             if self.right.getBalanceFactor() > 0:
                 self.right = self.right.rightRotate()
                 return self.leftRotate()                    
             else:
                 
                 return self.leftRotate()
          
         return self
        

    def leftRotate(self):
         temp = self.right
         temp2 = self.right.left
         self.right.left = self
         self.right = temp2
         self.height = self.heightCalc(self)
         temp.height = self.heightCalc(temp)
         self.balf = self.balCheck(self)
         temp.balf = self.balCheck(temp)
         
         return temp
        
       

    def rightRotate(self):
       
        tmp = self.left
        tmp1 = self.left.right
        self.left.right = self
        self.left = tmp1
        
        self.height = self.heightCalc(self)
    
        tmp.height = self.heightCalc(tmp)
        
        self.balf = self.balCheck(self)
        
        tmp.balf = self.balCheck(tmp)
        return tmp
```

```
#This example works properly
test = AVL(10)
test= test.insert(12)
test = test.insert(8)
print(test.data) #outputs 8
print(test.left.data) #outputs 7
print(test.right.data) #outputs 10

#In this case the rotation occurs but the parent node does not update its left child to the new node and still points to 8
test2 = AVL(10)
test2 = test2.insert(12)
test2 = test2.insert(8)
test2 = test2.insert(14)
test2 = test2.insert(6)
test2 = test2.insert(4)
print(test2.data)#outputs 10
print(test2.left.data)#outputs 8 but should be 6
#4 and 6 can no longer be accessed because they are lost
```

Comment: To be clear, the `class MyAVL():` represents a *node of* the tree, and not the overall tree, yes? Anyway, did you check that the tree looks right after the actual inserting part of `insert`, but before the rotation?

Comment: Also: think carefully about which node is `self` at the time that you start the rotation. You talk about how you could solve the problem if you had `parent` pointers, which you want to avoid for reasons of elegance; can you think of another way to know what the `parent` is *specifically in a recursive algorithm*? (Hint: where did the recursive call come from? Could that node help out somehow? I can think of at least two ways to communicate the necessary information between calls: in, and out.)

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code defines a class and quits without doing anything.  We expect a working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Comment: Also, consider designing the interface around rotation in a more useful way. You would only ever `balCheck` a node in order to see whether a rotation is required, right? So instead of grouping "figure out if the node is unbalanced" vs. "insert and then balance if necessary", the more rational grouping is "balance if necessary (where "necessary" entails the check)" vs. "insert (which entails a call to balance, since we should restore balance every time the tree is modified)".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In this case when the rotation is being called, self is the node 8, and the rotation method returns node 6 in its place. Im still drawing a blank as to how to update the parent node's left child.

Comment: Okay, so the parent node is the one with the `10`, right? How did we get to the point of trying to insert a child of `8`? Answer: because `10` recursively called the insertion method on its left child. So either we pass the information forward, by having `insert` calls accept a `parent` parameter and a "you are on the left side" parameter (and then if necessary we can call "hey, rebalance your left side" on that node); or we pass it backward, by `return`ing some kind of information that signals to the parent "you need to rotate your left side to rebalance".

Comment: Alternately, you can split up the work of rebalancing, by having `insert` return the root of the tree that should appear at the current position (which will be `self` if no rebalancing was needed), and then when you `return` from the recursion, *explicitly attach* the subtree that was `return`ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the `insert` method returns the new root of the subtree, after the insertion has been done and any needed rotations have happened. Your issue is that you're not using that return value when you recursively call `insert` on one of your child nodes.

```
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = MyAVL(data)                   
                else:
                    self.left = self.left.insert(data)     # update self.left here
            elif data >= self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = MyAVL(data)                        
                else:
                    self.right = self.right.insert(data)   # and self.right here
```